# Select an specific option from Dropdown Menu without values using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer to select and click an option in a dropdown menu in a navbar.

I already searched. There is always a `page.select` with the ID of the dropdown menu, but the thing is, there is no value option.

How can i, for example, make puppeteer click on the `Tools2` dropdown item?
Or, in a case of a dropdown menu with options that changes if you are a different user, how can i make puppeteer always click on the second option of a dropdown? Can i use CSS to make this work?

Here is the dropdown menu:

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Tools
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tools1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tools2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tools3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              User
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create users</a>
              <a method="get" class="dropdown-item" href="/usuario">Manage users</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
              <a method="get" action="/usuario/logout" class="dropdown-item" href="/">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CSS selector

If the dropdown items are already in the DOM you can use the [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS pseudo-class to select a specific one:

```js
await page.click('ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > a:nth-child(2)')
```

- `li:nth-child(2)` => the "Tools" menu (1 would be the "Home", while 3 would be the "User" nav-item)
- `a:nth-child(2)` => the second `<a>` element within the dropdown, "Tools2"

In case these list items are dynamically generated then you first need to open the dropdown:

```js
await page.click('ul > li:nth-child(2)')
```

Then proceed with selecting the 2nd `<a>` element.

### XPath selector

If the text content is more reliable than the (second) position within the dropdown then you can also use XPath's [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function to detect the element, return it as an [element handle](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-class-elementhandle) then click it :

```
const [item] = await page.$x('//a[contains(text(), "Tools2")]')
await item.click()
```

*Note:* `$x` returns an array of matched items, hence you either need to use an index of the item or use [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as in my example.

### $$eval approach

You can also use [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) to click the item based on its index (`[1]` will be the second element within the array of dropdown elements):

```js
await page.$$eval('ul > li:nth-child(2) > div > a', (elems) => elems[1].click())
```